# PHP date and time to time stamp

Tags: php

I have a date field and a time field for users to enter date and time, I then need to convert this to a time stamp. Here is my code

```
<input type='text' name='date' />
<input type='text' name='time' />
```

How can I put them both together and then generate a timestamp to place in database

any help appreciated 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) function:

```
$ts = strtotime($_POST['date'].' '.$_POST['time']);
```

Comment: You are wizard seems so simple now I look at it , thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$timestamp = strtotime('date');
```